# How to create Twitter Share link for my website containing short blogs

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, share

I want to create a Twitter share link from my website to share the first few lines of a blog by the user by fetching data from the PHP database. The data of the blog is stored in HTML format in the database. I tried fetching data and converting it to HTML decoded chars but when I try using that converted chars to Twitter link it re-adds HTML chars/tags before posting the tweet. Image attached for reference.

```
<script>
 
    function share(a) {
              let share_poem_ID = "#share-modal-" + a;
              document.querySelector(share_poem_ID).style.display = "block";
            }
    
    function shareClose(b) {
              let share_poem_ID = "#share-modal-" + b;
              document.querySelector(share_poem_ID).style.display = "none";
            }
</script>

<?php
    
    include 'connection.php';
    session_start();
    
    $query = " Select * From $dbtable";
    $result=@mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    
    foreach ($result as $row) {
     $Poem = $row['Poem'];
     $PoemShare =  htmlspecialchars_decode($Poem);
       echo "
        <div>
         <div class='the-poem'>
          <div class='poem'>$Poem</div>
         </div>
    
         <div class='poem-options'>
          <a class='share poem-option-list' id='report-btn-$ID' data-field-id='$ID' onclick='share($ID)'><i class='mdi mdi-share'></i></a>
         </div>
        </div>
    
      <!--- Share Modal --->
        <div class='modal-share' id='share-modal-$ID' role='dialog'>
         <div id='modal_content-share' class='modal-content-share'>
          <div class='page-container' id='page-content'>
            <span id='twitter$ID' class='share-option'>
              <i class='mdi mdi-twitter'></i>
                Share via Twitter
             </span>
           <script>
               $('#twitter$ID').on('click',function(){
                  window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=https://www.MartianJK.com/ms/login.php?u=$ID&text='$PoemShare'&hashtags=SpreadingSmiles', '_blank').focus();
                })
          </script>
         </div>      
        </div>
       </div>            
      ";
    
    }
    ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strip_tags()`](https://php.net/strip_tags):

```
$PoemShare =  strip_tags($Poem);
```

Or to keep `<br>` tag:

```
$PoemShare =  strip_tags($Poem, '<br>');
```

Comment: your answer is correct but it also strips the <br> tag and shows all content in one line. I want <br> tag / new line to function as is...

Comment: @JainishKothary I've updated the answer to keep `<br>` tags.

Comment: thanks that helped a little but can we convert <br /> to %0A for HTML link somehow?

Comment: You maybe can use `$Poem = str_replace('<br>', "\n", $Poem);` try also `urlencode()` to convert `"\n"` to `%0A`.

Comment: I just added these lines and it works perfect. Thanks for the help :  

       `$PoemShare = strlen($Poem) > 99 ? substr($Poem,0,100).'...' : $Poem;    
        $PoemShare = strip_tags($PoemShare, '<br>');
        $PoemShare = preg_replace('<<br />>','%0A', $PoemShare);
        $PoemShare = str_replace('&','%26', $PoemShare);
        $PoemShare = str_replace('"','%22', $PoemShare);
        $PoemShare = str_replace("'",'%27', $PoemShare);
        echo var_dump($PoemShare);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$PoemShare = strlen($Poem) > 99 ? substr($Poem,0,100).'...' : $Poem;    
$PoemShare = strip_tags($PoemShare, '<br>');
$PoemShare = preg_replace('<<br />>','%0A', $PoemShare);
$PoemShare = str_replace('&','%26', $PoemShare);
$PoemShare = str_replace('"','%22', $PoemShare);
$PoemShare = str_replace("'",'%27', $PoemShare);
echo var_dump($PoemShare);
```

This code made my work. Hope it helps others too. Credits to user @Syscall